# How to find first unique value in a column of SKU?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, conditional-formatting

So I have two columns, A & B, (like below). There's 2 components to the ID, the design (**CEN101A**) and the size (**-6**).

I'm trying find the first item of each design. So in this example, I would highlight (CEN106A-6, CEN101B-6, CEN101D-6, etc.). This is so I can use them as a parent for the other sizes.

I've tried many in-built functions but nothing seems to work. Is VBA able to easily find these values?

[image]

Comment: Maybe you could use a helper column and compare the `LEFT`most 7 characters of a cell to the `LEFT`most 7 characters of the previous cell? Assumes your IDs are ordered and the design component is always 7 characters.

Comment: @BigBen: That's the problem, design can be anywhere from 5-9 characters. I'm stumped.

Comment: Then find the position of the `-` and use that to strip out the design component.

Comment: But I need the design component left intact, I still need them to be in the same format, but I need to highlight the first size for each design (CEN101A-6 would be highlighted, CEN101B-6 would be highlighted, but the others would remain)

Comment: Yes, you'd use `LEFT` and `FIND`, or if your version of Excel supports it you could use `TEXTBEFORE`, in a conditional formatting rule.

Answer (score 2):

@BigBen is right, this is fairly easy if you can find what the actual design code is. For good measure I'd use a running count and add the hyphen back including a wildcard into the `COUNTIF()`:

[image]

Formula for conditional formatting rule on range `A2:A7`:

```
=COUNTIF(A$2:A2,@TEXTSPLIT(A2,"-")&"-*")=1
```

---

Without `TEXTSPLIT()`, use a combo of `LEFT()` and `FIND()` as per the comment by @[P.b](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12634230/p-b):

```
=COUNTIF(A$2:A2,LEFT(A2,FIND("-",A2))&"*")=1
```

Comment: Thank you! But ... is `@TEXTSPLIT` for newer than excel 2013? Doesn't seem to be recognized.

Comment: In that case you can follow the combination of left and find functions. I'm unable to add it as I just turned of my pc for the day. If no-one answered by tomorrow I'll edit it in.

Comment: `=COUNTIF(A$2:A2,LEFT(A2,FIND("-",A2))&"*")=1`

Comment: Hi, it's the same as JvdV posted, just a variation that doesn't require Office 365. @JvdV if you can edit it in your answer, then your answer will be accepted.